# Three lists within a tuple. How to make a dictionary?

Tags: python

I am trying to turn a list of tuples into a dictionary, but I keep on getting the same error: *"'unhashable type: 'list'"*. I believe this might be the case due to having lists within the tuple itself.

An example of how the list looks now:

```
[([183, 'receiver', 'A', '-', '67', '-', 'Amsterdam'],
  [31, 'donor', '-', 'O', '-', '62', 'Paris'],
  ['Amsterdam', 'Paris', 267])]
```

What I want is:

```
([183, 'receiver', 'A', '-', '67', '-', 'Amsterdam'],
  [31, 'donor', '-', 'O', '-', '62', 'Paris'],
  ['Amsterdam', 'Paris', 267]): 0
```

So, I want to equal the pair to 0.

Code:

```
result = [([183, 'receiver', 'A', '-', '67', '-', 'Amsterdam'],
          [31, 'donor', '-', 'O', '-', '62', 'Paris'],
          ['Amsterdam', 'Paris', 267])]

result_dict = {res: 0 for res in result}
```

Full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-cdd1628d9f41> in <module>
----> 1 result_dict = {res: 0 for res in result}

<ipython-input-37-cdd1628d9f41> in <dictcomp>(.0)
----> 1 result_dict = {res: 0 for res in result}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: then convert the list to tuples inside your tuples. What are the keys that you want?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the lists within the tuple is a distribution path. So 183 and 31 are linked together based on their geographic location. However, I want a dictionary that has that whole path.

Comment: just `[tuple(x) for x in megalist]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre but how do I turn it into a dictionary? The same error keeps occuring.

Comment: I see you have included an error traceback. Unfortunately the code there doesn't match up very well with the code you originally posted. Please update your question with your real code.

Comment: traceback: good, nocode: bad. Please include the code as well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Well, you'd need `tuple(tuple(x) for x in megalist)`, since a listcomp would make inner `tuple`s and an outer `list`, which would still be unhashable. It needs to be a `tuple` of `tuple`s (which themselves contain only immutable/hashable objects, recursively).

Comment: @AppieNouri: You use that technique to convert from the invalid `tuple` of `list`s to a valid `tuple` of `tuple`s. Once you've got the `tuple` of `tuple`s, it's a legal key.

Comment: @AppieNouri: You need to be a little more specific here. Is the whole `tuple` of `list`s intended to be a *single* key, or is each sub-`list` meant to be a *separate* key? What you say you want is a single key, but the code here `{res: 0 for res in result}`, is trying to make a `dict` with three separate keys, one for each sub-`list`, each mapping to `0`.

Comment: Side-note: You almost never want to preconstruct the keys for a `dict` like that; especially if the next step is to count inputs (because you're trying to count an input and don't want to handle creating keys on demand). The `collections` module provides a `Counter` class for counting, and `defaultdict` (which, used as `defaultdict(int)`, is similar to a `Counter`, but without the special features or accelerator `Counter` uses for counting iterables), both of which would let you count an input in a single pass (allowing your code to work on *any* iterable, including single-pass iterators).

Comment: @ShadowRanger the whole tuple of lists is intended to be a single key.

Comment: Yeah, so if `result = ...original definition...`, then `result = tuple(tuple(x) for x in result)` makes it a legal key, and `result_dict = {result: 0}` will work (or if `result_dict` already exists as a `dict`, then `result_dict[result] = 0`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I didn't think OP would want a tuple of tuples as key...

Answer (score 0):

As @ShadowRanger mentioned already, mutable object cannot be an key of dictionary. Python uses hashes to efficiently manage dictionary keys and list allows in place modifications that can change its hash value. Supporting it would mean each list (or other mutable object) modification would require tracking if hash is not used by some dictionary/set/etc and possibly to recompute hashing trees to reflect the change so it means serious performance loss. Another problem would be conflicts, consider this faulty code:

```
 key = [1]
 test = {key: 1, []: 2}
 key.pop()
```

What should be contents of `test` dictionary now?happen with `test` dictionary?

So for the example given, one of options is to convert your lists to tuples like so:

```
result = [([183, 'receiver', 'A', '-', '67', '-', 'Amsterdam'],
      [31, 'donor', '-', 'O', '-', '62', 'Paris'],
      ['Amsterdam',
```

So for the example given, one of options is to convert your lists to tuples like so:

```
result = [([183, 'receiver', 'A', '-', '67', '-', 'Amsterdam'],
      [31, 'donor', '-', 'O', '-', '62', 'Paris'],
      ['Amsterdam', 'Paris', 267])]
result_dict = {tuple(tuple(t for t in k) for k in p): 0 for p in result}
```

Still (again as @ShadowRanger suggested) also for me it looks like serious code smell that I would try to refactor to get rid of.